# Which Drupal permissions does a user need in order to see and change their relatives (contacts with permissioned relationships) in webform?

Tags: drupal, webform-civicrm, permissions, acl, user-account

I have a webform which users use to register themselves and their family members for events. If users have a login, it automatically populates their family members, who are contacts with permissioned relationships to the user, and all they have to do is select which events they are registering for this time.

Recently, most of my users are not having their families pre-populate, even though they do have family members, properly relationshiped and permissioned in the system. It works perfectly for anyone with admin privileges, but in this case I want most users to only see their spouses and children.

**Which permissions do I need to give them?**

I'm using Drupal 7.43, CiviCRM 4.6.18, Webform 7.x-4.12, and Webform Civicrm Integration 7.x-4.15+27-dev

Below are my current settings:
[image]
[image]
[image]

EDIT: I have now read this documentation, which makes me wonder whether my question should be about the CiviCRM ACL permissions instead, but I don't see how to do that either. https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/4.6/initial-set-up/permissions-and-access-control/

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the [Relationship Permissions as ACL](https://civicrm.org/extensions/relationship-permissions-acls) extension.

Answer (score -1):

Try setting CiviCRM: access Contact Dashboard for authenticated users.