# Troubleshooting relationship ACL Permissions

Tags: webform-civicrm, permissions, relationships, acl

This is the same issue listed [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/14804/which-drupal-permissions-does-a-user-need-in-order-to-see-and-change-their-relat) but my understanding of the issue has changed enough that it really isn't the same question anymore. (If any mods disagree I'm happy to take guidance on this point.) I am using the CiviCRM Webform Integration module in Drupal 7 to have users register both themselves and their children for events. Currently, they are not able to see their children even though their relationships are permissioned in CiviCRM. I  believe the issue is that my ACL permissioned relationships are broken.

I'm using CivCRM 4.6.18, Related Permissions 1.1,  Drupal 7.43, Webform 7.x-4.12, and Webform Civicrm Integration 7.x-4.15+27-dev

Any clues appreciated, even if you don't' have a complete answer!

Comment: Naomi - the users are 'logged in' or are they using a checksum?

Comment: Pete - They are logged in, and have the Drupal permission to view their own civi contact info. This functionality has worked before, I think it not working is part of having upgraded Civi a month or so ago, but since we weren't using it as heavily before it wasn't noticed.

Comment: Also, Admins can see the form working perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you follow the recipe at: https://civicrm.org/blog/sarahgladstone/recipe-for-handling-youth-registration-with-civicrm

Make sure you have both extensions:

Entity Settings Helper Extension (nz.co.fuzion.entitysetting) version 1.2

Related Permissions Extension (nz.co.fuzion.relatedpermissions) version 1.2

Comment: Looks promising, I'll give it a shot, thanks!